# Should both healthd and android.hardware.health@2.0-service.imx be running?

Tags: android, android-source, android-10.0, imx8, healthd

On my Android system, there are two separate healthd processes:

```
$ adb shell "ps -ef | grep health"
root          3535     1 3 14:33:18 ?     00:00:00 healthd
system        3548     1 5 14:33:18 ?     00:00:00 android.hardware.health@2.0-service.imx
```

They both use the same code from `system/core/healthd` and `hardware/interfaces/health/2.0/default`, but only `android.hardware.health@2.0-service.imx` uses code from `vendor/nxp-opensource/imx/health`.

- Is there any reason for both to run?
- Should NXP (or downstream vendor) have stopped the default Android `healthd` from building/running?

---

Update:

The `.rc` files for the two services differ:

```
smarc_mx8mq:/etc/init # cat healthd.rc                                                                                                                                     
service healthd /system/bin/healthd
    class hal
    critical
    group root system wakelock

smarc_mx8mq:/etc/init # cat /vendor/etc/init/android.hardware.health@2.0-service.imx.rc                                                                                    
service vendor.health-hal-2-0 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.health@2.0-service.imx
    class hal
    user system
    group system
    capabilities WAKE_ALARM
    file /dev/kmsg w
```

Removing `/etc/init/healthd.rc` from the built system causes the vanilla healthd not to start.  I have not yet noticed any ill effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

healthd is version 1.0 hal, it can be  removed. ref: [Removing healthd](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/health/deprecation#removing_healthd)